# Soundcloud json feed reader

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

Hi have this code but it's throwing an error. How can I output some of the items within the feed?

```
var jsonSoundCloudFeed = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/pete-snodden/tracks.json?client_id=a27703be6852256590c1921c5f8c7281";

            $.ajax({
                url: jsonSoundCloudFeed,
                data: {},
                dataType: "jsonp",
                callbackParameter: "jsoncallback",
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data){
                    $.each(data.kind, function(i, item) {

                        alert('yo');
                    });
                },
                error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus);
                    console.log("ERROR: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `each`-block in your `success` handler to something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(i + " " + item.kind);
});
```

See [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8F3rk/) for the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Like j0nes said, there's a bug in your success handler, but that's probably not even being executed: for JSONP, the extension should be ".js" instead of ".json".